# How to update list view after removing item from firebase data base?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want update the list view after I delete an item (using remove button) from firebase database, though the firebase database item gets deleted and the onChildRemoved method is called, the list view does not get updated.I would have to restart the app to see the updated list view.I tried everything on available on stackoverflow.

```
        package com.example.agasthya.travelbooking;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;

        import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
        import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
        import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
        import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;




        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            ChildEventListener mchild;
            private ListView mMessageListView;
            private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
            private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
            private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;

            private DatabaseReference mMessagesDataBaseReference;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);

                mMessagesDataBaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("travelbooking");
                 final List<Messages> friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();

                mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter( this, R.layout.list_item, friendlyMessages);
                mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

                mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);



                mchild=new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        Messages friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                        mMessageAdapter.add(friendlyMessage);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {Messages friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                        mMessageAdapter.remove(friendlyMessage);
                        mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };



                Button i =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
                        i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                             DatabaseReference ref = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
                             Query applesQuery = mMessagesDataBaseReference;

                            applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {int i=0;
                                for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();i++;





        if(i==1)break;
                                }}

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });}});

                mMessagesDataBaseReference.addChildEventListener(mchild);

            }


                }
```

Message Adapter class

```
            package com.example.agasthya.travelbooking;


            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
            import android.widget.TextView;

            import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;

            import java.util.List;

            public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Messages> {
                public MessageAdapter(ChildEventListener context, int resource, List<Messages> objects) {
                    super(context, resource, objects);
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                    }


                    TextView messageTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
                    TextView authorTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
                    TextView authorTextView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView2);


                    Messages message = getItem(position);

                        messageTextView.setText("From :"+message.getFrom()+"\n");

                    authorTextView.setText("To :"+message.getTo()+"\n");
                    authorTextView2.setText("Name :"+message.getName()+"\n");

                    return convertView;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Add **MessageAdapter** class in your question.

Comment: Added the Message Adapter class

Answer (score 0):

```
 package com.example.agasthya.travelbooking;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;

        import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
        import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
        import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
        import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;




        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            ChildEventListener mchild;
            private ListView mMessageListView;
            private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
            private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
            private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;

            private DatabaseReference mMessagesDataBaseReference;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);

                mMessagesDataBaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("travelbooking");
                 final List<Messages> friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();

                mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter( this, R.layout.list_item, friendlyMessages);
                mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

                mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);



                mchild=new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        Messages friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                        mMessageAdapter.add(friendlyMessage);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {Messages friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                         mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter( this, R.layout.list_item, friendlyMessages);
                mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };



                Button i =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
                        i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                             DatabaseReference ref = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
                             Query applesQuery = mMessagesDataBaseReference;

                            applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {int i=0;
                                for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();i++;





        if(i==1)break;
                                }}

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });}});

                mMessagesDataBaseReference.addChildEventListener(mchild);

            }


                }
```

Try this.

Comment: I have tried this, I get a context problem whether activity's context or ChildEventlistener context.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.agasthya.travelbooking;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;

        import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
        import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
        import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
        import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;




        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            ChildEventListener mchild;
            private ListView mMessageListView;
            private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
            private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
            private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;

            private DatabaseReference mMessagesDataBaseReference;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);

                mMessagesDataBaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("travelbooking");
                 final List<Messages> friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();

                mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter( this, R.layout.list_item, friendlyMessages);
                mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

                mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);



                mchild=new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        Messages message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                        friendlyMessage.add(message);
                        mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Messages message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                        friendlyMessages.remove(message);
                        mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };



                Button i =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
                        i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                             DatabaseReference ref = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
                             Query applesQuery = mMessagesDataBaseReference;

                            applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {int i=0;
                                for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();i++;





        if(i==1)break;
                                }}

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });}});

                mMessagesDataBaseReference.addChildEventListener(mchild);

            }


                }
```

Try this Code.

Comment: Thanks for code but, the list view is still not getting updated.

Comment: The item is removed from the firebase data base but list-view is not updating,just like my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.example.agasthya.travelbooking;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;

    import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;




    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ChildEventListener {
        ChildEventListener mchild;
        private ListView mMessageListView;
        private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
        private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
        private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;

        private DatabaseReference mMessagesDataBaseReference;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);

            mMessagesDataBaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("travelbooking");
             final List<Messages> friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();

            mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter( this, R.layout.list_item, friendlyMessages);
            mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);



            mchild= (ChildEventListener) this;



            Button i =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
                    i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                         DatabaseReference ref = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
                         Query applesQuery = mMessagesDataBaseReference;

                        applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {int i=0;
                            for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();i++;





    if(i==1)break;
                            }}

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });}});

            mMessagesDataBaseReference.addChildEventListener(mchild);

        }

               @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Messages friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                    mMessageAdapter.add(friendlyMessage);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {Messages friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                    mMessageAdapter.remove(friendlyMessage);
                    mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
  }
```

Try this